# Symfony - Changing templates for embedded forms

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have made a form which embedded forms to add new records in a one-to-many relationship with ajax, my question is, where do I edit the template for the embedded form? because I would assume this would be in _form.php but it doesn't seem to use that template

Thanks in advance

Comment: in fact it does come from the same `_form` partial as the main form. Form elements in symfony by default render as a table row, so this might be what is causing your confusion. Could you please tell us what you're wanting to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are adding fields by ajax you can do the response of the ajax with some template. For example if you have a mail field you could do:

```
public function executeAddMailForm($request)
{
    $this->forward404unless($request->isXmlHttpRequest());

    $mail = new MailForm();

    //action logic...

    return $this->renderPartial('addMail',array('form' => $form));
}
```

and make a **_addMail** template:

```
<div class="form-ajax-item">
    <div class="form-ajax-label">
        <?=$form['mail']->renderLabel()?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-ajax-field">
        <?=$form['mail']->render()?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way you can do the ajax response using templates.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it does come from the same _form partial as the main form. Form elements in symfony by default render as a table row, so this might be what is causing your confusion. Could you please tell us what you're wanting to do.

There is documentation on how to do this and a very detailed example on the symfony website [see here](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms). It's pretty in depth and can look a bit daunting but I recommend you read through it and make sure you  take the time to **actually** understand it.